# Jmeter combine Json extractor variables to pass into request

Tags: json, variables, jmeter, extract, multiple-value

There's a certain web request which has the following response:

```
{
"data": {
    "articles": [
        {
            "id": "1355",
            "slug": "smart-device-connectivity's-impact-on-homes-workplaces",
            "title": "Smart device connectivity's impact on homes, workplaces",
            "published_at": "2022-01-28T21:30:00.000Z",
            "avg_rating": 0,
            "click_count": 60,
        },
        {
            "id": "1363",
            "slug": "you-need-to-nurture-and-amplify-human-capabilities",
            "title": "You need to nurture and amplify human capabilities",
            "published_at": "2022-01-28T19:00:00.000Z",
            "avg_rating": 0,
            "click_count": 22,
        }]}}
```

There are a total of 702 records which may increase or decrease over the coming months. Now I have been successfully able to extract ID & slug into separate variables. My aim is to pass these two variables into another request in the following format so that I can eventually run that 702 times or number of times = ID array or slug array size:

testurl.com/insight/${id}/${slug}

Example:
testurl.com/insight/1355/smart-device-connectivity's-impact-on-homes-workplaces
testurl.com/insight/1363/you-need-to-nurture-and-amplify-human-capabilities

I made use of Foreach controller & was able to pass slug but ID does not work. Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using ForEach Controller for iterating `slug` variable the `id` one needs to be handed a little bit differently:

- use `__jm__ForEach Controller__idx` [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) to get current iteration of the ForEach Controller
- use [__intSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) to increment it by 1 as the above variable is zero-based
- use [__V() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables/) to calculate the value of `id_x` variable

putting everything together:

```
testurl.com/insight/${__V(id_${__intSum(${__jm__ForEach Controller__idx},1,)},)}/${slug}
```

Answer (score 0):

What error do you get?

I was able to emulate the same

I saved your json in a variable
[image]

Foreach controller
[image]

another JSON inside foreach
[image]

Using the extracted values
[image]

Overall JMX structure
[image]

Final output
[image]